# Не получается установить соединение с базой данных postgres в asyncpg

Tags: python-3.x, linux, база-данных, postgresql, docker

Есть вот такой код создания бд

```
async def create_db():
    create_db_command = open("create_db.sql").read()

    logging.info("Connecting to database...")
    conn: asyncpg.Connection = await asyncpg.connect(user=PG_USER,
                                                     password=PG_PASS,
                                                     host=host)
    await conn.execute(create_db_command)
    await conn.close()
    logging.info("Table users created")


async def create_pool():
    return await asyncpg.create_pool(user=PG_USER,
                                     password=PG_PASS,
                                     host=host)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(create_db())
```

Переменные PG_USER, PG_PASS и host инициализируются с помощью переменных окружения, задающихся в файле.env

```
PGHOST=db
PG_USER=postgres
PG_PASS=123456
```

Я использую операционную систему ubuntu, постгрес работает в контейнере докера.
Контейнер запускаю с помощью файла yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6080:8080
```

Чтоб зайти в постгрес через админ я ввожу логин postgres, пороль 123456 и сервер db, но при попытке коннектиться к db через скрипт питона возникает ошибка, связанная с хостом.(ниже то, что выводится в терминал)

> sql.py [LINE:14] #INFO     [2020-08-15 01:58:31,909]  Connecting to
> database... Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/anton/dev/Bots/EnglishGitBot/sql.py", line 31, in 
> loop.run_until_complete(create_db())   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in
> run_until_complete
> return future.result()   File "/home/anton/dev/Bots/EnglishGitBot/sql.py", line 15, in create_db
> conn: asyncpg.Connection = await asyncpg.connect(user=PG_USER,   File
> "/home/anton/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py",
> line 1718, in connect
> return await connect_utils._connect(   File "/home/anton/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py",
> line 674, in _connect
> raise last_error   File "/home/anton/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py",
> line 663, in _connect
> con = await _connect_addr(   File "/home/anton/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py",
> line 632, in _connect_addr
> tr, pr = await asyncio.wait_for(   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 483, in wait_for
> return fut.result()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 986, in
> create_connection
> infos = await self._ensure_resolved(   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1365, in
> _ensure_resolved
> return await loop.getaddrinfo(host, port, family=family, type=type,   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line
> 825, in getaddrinfo
> return await self.run_in_executor(   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
> result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
> for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name
> resolution

Какое значение должно быть у хоста, чтоб соединение установилось? я пробовал вбивать ip докер контейнера, в котором запущен bd и локальный адрес.

Comment: 127.0.0.1, и нужно уже пробросить порт докера на хост. это можно сделать через ports.

Comment: @alex, я пробовал вводить 127.0.0.1:порт_докера, не помогло. Или я не правильно понял?

Comment: добавьте в вопрос информацию как вы запускаете контейнер

Comment: @alex, добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать так чтоб контейнеры друг друга видели. Как это сделать ? Раньше это делалось с помощью [link](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/)
Если вы уже зашли по ссылке то увидели что это уже давно старо и использовать это не нужно.
Как же сделать так чтоб контейнеры друг друга видели ? Очевидно что через network. Можно начать читать [отсюда](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/)

Теперь в остатке. Как вам через Compose сделать видимыми друг другу контейнеры. Я прям сейчас не уверен, ибо у меня описаны в compose всё что я хочу описать, однако мне думается что по-умолчанию можно не описывать сеть для ваших сервисов и достаточно просто будет указать hostname в вашем сервисе db

Можете посмотреть все о чем я говорил на этом [примере](https://github.com/maxi-booking/d8base-backend/blob/master/.docker/docker-compose.yml)

Answer (score 1):

Измените ваш докер композ файл, добавив туда линковку порта докер контейнера с базой на хостовую систему

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123456
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6080:8080
```

После этого требуется перезапустить командами

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose up -d
```

Чтобы поднятые контейнеры перечитали композ файл. Теперь можно запускать код указав в качестве хоста для подключения к БД 127.0.0.1, а в качестве порта 5432 (по умолчанию для постгреса)

Comment: не работает, пробовал вводить в качестве хоста и 127.0.0.1 и 127.0.0.1:5432. При такой конфигурации yml файла, что нужно передавать в переменную host?